# Drawing/plot is not continuous (mouse events involved)

Tags: java, swing

I'm having issues with a java class project. The first step consist in drawing a pattern, so I thought well, this can't be hard. And it isn't, but there one thing that really bothers me. First, check the screenshot below :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APHcv.png)

My problem is that this was done without releasing the mouse, so the drawing should be continuous. Instead of this, there's holes in it. I'm thinking this is related to the way mouse events are transmitted, But I have no idea how to tweak this.

The drawing zone is a JPanel. There is a set of Points that is used to paint the container on mouse events. Pressing add the first point, dragging the others, released clear the drawing zone.

Hope I was specific enough. Thanks for your time!

**edit** : Forgot the code. http://pastebin.com/RyXiGsvm

Comment: without posting the sample code you can't expect any help.

Comment: My mistake. The post was edited.

Comment: "Forgot the code."  Forgot the question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you store mouse points obtained in mouseDrag processing. Mouse drag happens from after some time interval so if you move mouse relatively fast you just got points. TO drai it you can use drawLine() passing pairs of point. So you'll have lines.

Answer (score 2):

StanislavL's right that mouseMove/mouseDrag events are not generated for every pixel you move the mouse cursor over. Why don't you want to use lines? If the issue is that the result is ugly and jagged, you might consider using cubic splines instead. GeneralPath.curveTo provides an easy way to do this. If getting the control points right is a pain, you can also use GeneralPath.quadTo; this is a quadratic approximation that won't look quite as good, but you can easily just pass in the last three points from mouseDrags.